# Make Azure Logic App SFTP trigger "forget" the files it has already seen

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an SFTP trigger in a Logic App that has already "seen" all of the files on the SFTP server, so when I try to run the trigger, it gets skipped (because there are no new files). Is there any way to make the trigger "forget" the files it has already seen so that next time I run the trigger, it gets fired for every file that exists on the server? I assume the trigger stores its state somewhere (e.g. timestamp of last trigger or whatever), so if I could clear that state it would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a direct answer to your question, but depending on your environment, your processes, and your functional needs, I can suggest you to try one of the following approaches:

1. If it's ok to make manual changes in your Logic App or in the API connection it's using (i.e. if it's your dev or test environment) then updating the Logic App manually (change the trigger to a different type, save the Logic App, change the trigger back to the original one, save the Logic App again) will reset its state, and all SFTP files will be detected. If amending the Logic App is not an option, the API connection could possibly be deleted and redeployed to the same effect; all SFTP files would be detected by the Logic App (if my memory serves me right).
2. I found that the easiest way, which doesn't require any changes in the Logic App, is to move the files from the SFTP folder temporarily to a different folder, and in a few minutes to move (or copy) them back. The Created or Modified date and time of the files will become different, so the Logic App will not recognize them as already processed in the past, and detect them again. I recommend using this approach (if you don't wish to redesign the workflow).
3. Finally, in some scenarios e.g. when the new files arrive at the source SFTP folder rarely, say on a daily basis, it might make sense to redesign the Logic App to use the [Recurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence?tabs=consumption#add-the-recurrence-trigger) trigger instead of the [When a file is added or updated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connectors/built-in/reference/sftp/#when-a-file-is-added-or-updated) SFTP trigger. The updated workflow would look as follows: once in a while (depending on the recurrence trigger settings) list files in the source SFTP folder; if files exist then process them one by one, moving them to an archive SFTP folder as the last step of the process; at the end of the workflow all processed files would be moved to the archive SFTP folder; next time the Logic App is run it will list the files in the source SFTP folder again, and only new files will be processed.